# How to regex extract alpha portion immediately after an underscore in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, regex, regexextract

Using Google sheets, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have data that comes in like this:

```
xta_GAM-1a (61095)
xta_SM (61096)
xta_GAM2 (61156)
xta_GAM-1b (61161)
AO CPC ALL GAM
AO CPC ALL PA
AO CPC ALL SM
AO CPC ALL TPP
```

I want to extract only the first alpha portion after the underscore, or failing that just the last alpha portion, so resulting in this:

```
GAM
SM
GAM
GAM
GAM
PA
SM
TPP
```

How can I pull this off?

EDIT:  @amit's answer got me most of the way there, and I figured out the last part on my own.  Current solution is:

`=if(iserror(search("_",C1)),REGEXEXTRACT(C1,".* (.*)$"),iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(C1,".*_", ""),"[A-Z]+"),""))`

I will award to Amit unless anyone has something more compact, elegant, etc.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Please read the tags on your question **before** you post to the wrong site.

Comment: How is this off topic?  I'm asking about regex within Google Sheets.  Two of the tags that were available to me were regex, and google-spreadsheets.  What do you have a problem with?

Comment: OK fine, they shouldn't provide that tag as an option when posting the question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,".*_", ""),"[A-Z]+")
```

Comment: Hot damn, a little slow but works perfectly... thanks!  I'm going to wait a bit before awarding best answer just in case someone comes up with an even cleaner, shorter, faster, or otherwise better solution.

Comment: Crud, I overlooked another form of data shows up regularly, amending my question to include this form.

Comment: Figured out the rest of the solution on my own!  `=if(iserror(search("_",C1)),REGEXEXTRACT(C1,".* (.*)$"),iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(C1,".*_", ""),"[A-Z]+"),""))`